Can I mix HAL USART2 initialization with Baremetal USART6 manipulation?
I am writing a code to read ADC data from an AC voltage sensor. I used HAL to initialize ADC 1 and USART2 for checking the values in Putty. However, I would like to use direct register manipulation to send data to USART6 so that it can transmit the data to a wifi module which sends the data to a website for monitoring. However, I am not getting correct values in USART6 (confirmed by using serial monitor in IDE which I am using to check data received by the wifi module which is ESP32 to be specific). The output is gibberish as opposed to the data obtained from USART2. Is it possible that there's clashing between the initialization of USART2 in HAL and USART6 in bare metal?
If I try using bare metal for USART2 and USART6, would there be any difference? I have read from another question here that you cannot mix HAL and bare metal code when accessing the same peripheral, but I wonder if that applies for the GPIO peripherals I'd be using as well (ADC GPIOs in HAL and USART GPIOs in bare metal)

I don't see a problem with using the HAL for one UART and bare-metal for another. Sounds like you've probably just not initialised it properly.

What makes you to think that problem is at STM32 side and not the wifi module side? Observe the UART signals using logic analyzer/oscilloscope, or some "known good" UART receiver.

cross-post https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/mixing-hal-and-direct-register-manipulation/td-p/680425

Yes I have indeed not initialized it properly. It turns out that the default HAL config for system clock makes it so that the sysclock frequency is 84MHz. The baud rate calculations were affected by this so I had to redo them. Thanks for the help. @wek shared the link of my post in the ST community. Thank you.
